# Get index and column name for a particular value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
                             A                                        B
0                     Exporter                       Invoice No. & Date
1                 ABC PVT LTD.        ABC/1234/2022-23 DATED 20/08/2022
2                 1234/B, XYZ,
3           ABCD, DELHI, INDIA               Proforma Invoice No. Date.
4                                    AB/CDE/FGH/2022-23/1234 20.08.2022
5                    Consignee          Buyer (If other than consignee)
6                      ABC Co.
8            P.O BOX NO. 54321
9              Berlin, Germany
```

Now I want to search for a value in this DataFrame, and store the index and column name in 2 different variables.

**For example:**
If I search "Consignee", I should get

```
index = 5
column = 'A'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you really want the index/column of the match, you can use a mask and `stack`:

```
df.where(df.eq('Consignee')).stack()
```

output:

```
5  A    Consignee
dtype: object
```

As list:

```
df.where(df.eq('Consignee')).stack().index.tolist()
```

output: `[(5, 'A')]`

Comment: Thanks, I will get index and column name using result[0][0] and result[0][1].